# pipenv install django==2.1 not working on google collab

Tags: python, django, pip, google-colaboratory, pipenv

*I have already installed pipenv using,*
**pip install pipenv** *on the directory which was installed successfully. But*

**pipenv install Django==2.1** *does not seem to work. In fact, no command is getting executed using* **pipenv.**

**pip install pipenv**

Collecting pipenv
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/b4/3ffa55f77161cff9a5220f162670f7c5eb00df52e00939e203f601b0f579/pipenv-2018.11.26-py3-none-any.whl (5.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.2MB 5.5MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pipenv) (40.9.0)
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 (from pipenv)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/f8/50c2b7dbc99e05fce5e5b9d9a31f37c988c99acd4e8dedd720b7b8d4011d/virtualenv_clone-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pipenv) (2019.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pipenv) (19.0.3)
Collecting virtualenv (from pipenv)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/5d/314c760d4204f64e4a968275182b7751bd5c3249094757b39ba987dcfb5a/virtualenv-16.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 17.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: virtualenv-clone, virtualenv, pipenv
Successfully installed pipenv-2018.11.26 virtualenv-16.4.3 virtualenv-clone-0.5.3

**pipenv install Django==2.1**

File "", line 1
    pipenv install Django==2.1
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

*

> Anything on Google Colab suggestions would be very helpful!

*

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is a shell command. I assume Google Colab has made `pip` available as a special command(*) (without the `%` syntax), but that doesn't mean any other shell command works as such. That is why you get a `SyntaxError`: it is not recognised as normal Python syntax.

You can work around it by using `!pipenv install 'Django==2.1'` (the single quotes may not be necessary, but the exclamation work is).

I doubt, however, that you really need a virtual environment in the first place. This is not on your regular machine, where you may want to keep dependencies apart. Instead, just start a new notebook for a new project, and install Django as normal: `pip install Django`. I wouldn't bother with `pipenv` and virtual environments inside notebooks. There doesn't seem to be any use for it.

---

(*) Try, for example, `pip?`, and note the help lists its usage with the `%pip` syntax. I assume that, if it's not ambiguous, Colab will use `%pip` when called as `pip`. The same works for, for example, `ls` instead of `%ls`.